# Permission denied for root and "cd /" issue

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I am having an issue, first of all I can not cd freely from the terminal, for example:

```
[eldritch@localhost ~]$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
[eldritch@localhost ~]$ cd /Downloads
bash: cd: /Downloads: No such file or directory
```

Second issue, I am trying to run a file and i get this:

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# ls
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.24.run  yakuake-2.9.9.tar.xz

[root@localhost Downloads]# ./yakuake-2.9.9.tar.xz 
bash: ./yakuake-2.9.9.tar.xz: Permission denied
```

Comment: .tar.xz is a "zipped" file. Try: "tar -xvf <filename>" As for the permissions, please do a "ls -al" en give us the output for the line with Downloads

Comment: Please don't take it the wrong way, but I would suggest you to go through a couple of Linux tutorials. The answers here will surely help but you will get into additional issues if you don't get a few notions first. For example this: http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd recommend you go through [a tutorial](http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php) for the Linux shell, if you're not familiar with it. There's some basic things you need to know about how files are organized and how permissions work.

If you run `ls`, your shell will show you all files and directories in the *current* working directory. To get to your downloads directory, you have to type:

```
cd Downloads
```

and not

```
cd /Downloads
```

That is because `/` is the root of your disk, where usually there's no downloads directory. To see your current working directory, type

```
pwd
```

which would print something like `/home/dima/`. That's where `Downloads` is: `/home/dima/Downloads`.

---

As for your second issue, you cannot execute a `.tar.xz` file. What you're trying to do only works with files that are marked as executable, which are typically only scripts or programs. Archives like `.tar.xz` need to be untarred:

```
tar -xvf file.tar.xz
```

If you're on a system where `tar` doesn't have support for this format, maybe you need

```
sudo apt-get install xz-utils
```

before.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you are at your home folder, or `~`. Then, you are `cd`ing into `/Downloads`, which is on the root.

The solution is

```
cd Downloads
```

or

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Your second problem is that you are trying to *execute* a compressed file.
You want to decompress it, with

```
xz yakuake-2.9.9.tar.xz
```

You may need to install `xz` first. If you need help with that, tell us what is your distribution.